# Character triples isomorphism and real characters

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

A character triple is a triple of the form $(G,N,\theta)$ where $G$ is a finite group, $N$ is normal in $G$, $\theta \in Irr(N)$ and $\theta$ is $G$-invariant. For the concept of character triple isomorphism, I refer to Definition $11.23$ of "Character Theory on Finite Groups", Isaacs.

Let be $(\tau,\sigma) \colon (G,N,\theta) \to (\Gamma,M,\phi)$ a character triple isomorphism. Via $(\tau,\sigma)$, some properties are preserved, for example if $\theta$ is afforded by an $\mathbb{F}$-representation and $G$ is perfect, then for every $N\le U\le G$ and $\eta \in Irr(U\mid \theta)$, then $\mathbb{F}(\eta)=\mathbb{F}(\eta^\tau)$ (this appears in an article of Navarro and Tiep of 2009). Unfortunately, for real character the Schur-Frobenius indicator is defenitely an obstacle. If $\theta$ is real, I see no way to make the triple isomorphism send real character in real characters. If $\Gamma$ and $M$ are respectively the Schur covering and the Schur multiplier of $G/N$ and $\Gamma$ is known, then we can get reality provided some uniqueness properties. Namely, if $\Gamma$ has a unique character $\chi$ over $\phi$ of a certain degree, then we can pull the reality to $\chi^{\tau^{-1}}$. The same if $\Gamma$ has an odd number of characters with the same degree, then one of the correspondent character in $G$ are real. These both statements follow easely from the fact that the complex conjugation acts on $Irr(G\mid \theta)$ preserving the degrees. But if none of these conditions are satisfied, I don't know how to proceed. A general tool would be nice.

Just to make it easier, if $\phi=1_M$, then $Irr(\Gamma\mid \phi)=Irr(G/N)$, moreover $\phi^{\tau^{-1}}$ is an extension $\hat \theta$ to $G$ and the map $\tau^{-1}$ is just the map $\gamma\to \hat \phi \gamma$. However, I don't know if $\theta$ is afforded by a real representation, and even if it does, to adapt the proof in Isaacs is kind of difficult. It boils down to the extendiblity of the representation affording $\theta$ or similar criteria (see $11.27$ of Isaacs' book , for example).
I mean, it seems that we are in the context of Gallagher's Theorem, nevertheless, though easier, I can't say much more than this and only some hightlights in this situation would be very useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

I apologize for answering to your question so late. Probably you do not need an answer anymore but I suppose it may still be useful to people facing the same problem.

I also have to apologize for the shameless self-promotion I am going to engage in, since the answer to your question can be found in a paper I recently published.

In fact, the question is answered by Theorem 3.6 of [G., Pellegrini, Sylow normalizers and irreducible characters with small cyclotomic field of values](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2022.05.030) (you may also use Theorem 3.5 of the [preliminary arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.13825.pdf)).

In particular, first we have that, if $(\tau, \sigma) : (G,N,\theta) \mapsto (\Gamma, M, \phi)$ is a character triple isomorphism and $\theta$ is real-valued, then also $\phi$ is real-valued. Moreover, if we also have that $G/N$ is a perfect group, then $\chi \in Irr(G \mid \theta)$ is real-valued if and only if $\chi^{\tau} \in Irr(\Gamma \mid \phi)$ is real-valued.

The condition of $G/N$ being perfect cannot be avoided. In fact, suppose that $G$ is a cyclic group of order 4, $N < G$ is a cyclic group of order 2 and $\theta \in Irr(N)$ is the only non-principal irreducible character of $N$. Then, the triples $(G,N,\theta)$ and $(G,N,1_N)$ are isomorphic. However, while all the characters in $Irr(G \mid 1_N)$ are real-valued, none of the characters in $Irr(G \mid \theta)$ is actually real-valued. Notice that, in this case, $\theta$ is afforded by a rational representation (actually, it is a rational representation itself), so I would say that the Schur index does not help in this situation.